# Spring Boot controllers: metrics break request mapping

Tags: java, spring, metrics

I'm trying to add Dropwizard metrics to Spring Boot controller methods.

Like following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/plan")
@ExposesResourceFor(Plan.class)
public class PlanController implements RelProvider {

...
    @Timed(name = "my.metric")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<Plan>> getPlan(@PathVariable String id) {
        Plan plan = service.getPlan(id);
        return createResponse(HttpStatus.OK, plan);
    }
```

Once I add  `@Timed(name = "my.metric")` to **any** of controller request handling methods - all the methods start to responding with the 404.

Without `@Timed` annotated methods controller work fine. Putting `@Timed` onto methods of the other classes also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the RelProvider interface.
Your proxy needs to be a CGLIB, and not a JDK dynamic proxy.
You can remove the interface or change the set proxyTargetClass=true in your EnableMetrics annotation.